# Rails - Devise: Change Password and send mail notify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I want to send a mail notification that you changed your password in Devise, but I have no idea how to. I finish the Change Password job by adding `<%= link_to "Change your password", edit_user_registration_path%>` to application.html.erb.

Answer (score 3):

Since Devise 3.5.3 notify after change pasword functionality has been built-in, but it is disabled by default. To enable it, open config/initializers/devise.rb and make this change and restart your app.

```
- # config.send_password_change_notification = false
+   config.send_password_change_notification = true
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Notify-users-via-email-when-their-passwords-change

Answer (score 0):

You want to use ActionMailer.

See the one of these guides for details:

- [Rails guide on ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)
- [This tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-send-email.htm) on sending email using rails, or
- ["Sending Email from Your App"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp) in Heroku help

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many gems available to send mails.
Try this: https://github.com/benprew/pony